# .NET Core 3.0 Publish for ARM64

Tags: .net-core, publish, arm64, .net-core-3.0

Does anyone know how to publish a .NET Core 3.0 application for ARM64?
I can only select "linux-arm" but no "linux-arm64".
Setting linux-arm in combination with x64 also doesnt work. It says the settings are not compatible.

As stated here it should already be supported: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.0/3.0-supported-os.md

Comment: what platforms and identifiers are in your csproj?

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean? What did you try? What runtime IDs did you use in the command line or the project file?

Comment: The link points to the supported OSs, not the list of runtime identifiers. That list is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The linked article points to the supported OSs, not the list of runtime identifiers. An explanation of an RID and a list of common ones can be found in [.NET Core RID Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog). The *full* list can be found at the CoreFX repo, in [runtime.json](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/pkg/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/runtime.json). `linux-arm64` is included but that's only the *base* OS. There are a lot of specific identifiers like `"debian-arm64"`, `"debian.10-arm64"`, `"rhel-arm64"` and `"ubuntu-arm64"`. You'll have to use the RID that corresponds to your distribution.

As the RID catalog explains, a runtime identifier consists of the OS, OS version, architecture and optional extra qualifiers.

> [os].[version]-[architecture]-[additional qualifiers]

`ubuntu-arm64` is the generic Ubuntu version for ARM64 while `ubuntu.19.04-arm64` targets Ubuntu 19.04 specifically.

There's no specific version for Raspbian. If you want to target Raspberry in general, you'll have to use `linux-arm`. If you want to take advantage of the 4GB RAM model, *assuming you already use a 64bit OS* you may be able to target `linux-arm64`.

Answer (score 10):

The linux-arm64 isn't available from the publish profile settings, but if you build it using linux-arm and manually edit your `.pubxml` file afterwards, it works on the pi just fine. As the link you provided shows, it is supported. It seems it hasn't been added to the tooling yet.

Just publish as usual and then edit `.pubxml`

Change
`<RuntimeIdentifier>linux-arm</RuntimeIdentifier>`
to
`<RuntimeIdentifier>linux-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>`

Then you can publish on a 64bit Raspberry pi.

[image: screenshot example]

[image: voila!]