# Can't run compiled .Net Core application on Ubuntu host

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, .net-core, mono

I have 2 mini-PCs, both with linux-arm.

The first host - is TV box with S912 CPU corelec installed on it.

The second host - Raspberry Pi 4 Model b with freshly Ubuntu Server + lubuntu-desktop installation.

The code of .Net Core 3.1 app is simplest template of C# console app:

using System;

```
namespace test2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

The C# .Net Core Console app compiled in MS VS 2019 with parameters:
[image]

`<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
  </PropertyGroup>`

App uploaded on both hosts, `chmod +x test2` executed, running with './test2'.

The result on First host (corelec):

`CoreELEC:/tmp # ./test2
Hello World!`

Ie, linux-arm application works well on it.

The result on second host (Raspberry Pi 4):

`ubuntu@ubuntu:/tmp$ chmod +x test2
ubuntu@ubuntu:/tmp$ ./test2
-bash: ./test2: No such file or directory`

Why it doesn't work on the second, any ideas?

P. S. There is not linux-arm64 option in MS VS 2019 compilation options:
[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that `test2` exists on the second host? `No such file or directory` generally means the file isn't even there.

Comment: A raspberry pi uses an armv8 64 bit processor. You probably should be targeting it using `linux-arm64` instead of `linux-arm`.

Comment: To Omair Majid - yep, it's on the host and I see it with `ls`, `chmod +x test2` see it too.

Comment: And yeh, good idea about linux-arm64, but there is no such option like `linux-arm64` in compilation options:

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58474819/net-core-3-0-publish-for-arm64

Comment: To Lex Li: Oh, thank you, my time saver! ))) `<RuntimeIdentifier>ubuntu-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>` did the trick! Thank you a lot!