# Run .NET 5.0 application on ARM64 CPU

Tags: c#, linux, arm64

I'm moving one console app from my PC to RPI4. I've installed Ubuntu 21.04 OS there.
The app written in .NET 5.0 architecture. I've published it using following configuration[image: enter profile settings]

Note: I've also tried Self-contained mode but it yielded same error.

First problem I encountered was fact I needed to install runtimes and SDK for .NET5 and so I did. Here's what I have installed:[image: dotnet info]
and here's ENV:[image: env info]

Then I realised VS only offers arm32 runtime. I found this quide on internet: https://forum.armbian.com/topic/4764-running-32-bit-applications-on-aarch64/

Now I'm stuck with following error.

> Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while
> copying content to a stream.  --->
> System.IO.Compression.ZLibException: The underlying compression
> routine could not be loaded correctly.  --->
> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library
> 'libSystem.IO.Compression.Native' or one of its dependencies. In order
> to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG
> environment variable: liblibSystem.IO.Compression.Native: cannot open
> shared object file: No such file or directory    at
> Interop.zlib.InflateInit2_(ZStream& stream, Int32 windowBits)    at
> System.IO.Compression.ZLibNative.ZLibStreamHandle.InflateInit2_(Int32
> windowBits)    at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.InflateInit(Int32
> windowBits)

It seems like it has something to do with fact that it's deployed for arm32 while rpi4 has arm64 CPU but I couldn't find any workaround.

Comment: there's .NET runtime for ARM64 on Linux https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0

Comment: I have installed this but since the app is actually 32 bit I also had to install ARM32 runtimes to make it at least start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone would find this question, it turned out that VS can't deploy apps on 64bit ARM linux. You need to install 32bit version of linux on RPI to make it work. Not best solution, but works well.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use right RID. On your screenshot this is `Target runtime` to use `linux-arm64`. You can't select this value, but you can write.

- List of RIDs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog
- Useful question: [.NET Core 3.0 Publish for ARM64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58474819/net-core-3-0-publish-for-arm64)

I used dotnet6, self-contained deployment mode and run it on Raspberry Pi 3 with Ubuntu x64 (aarch64).

Comment: Seems promising. But I have already deployed to and been using 32bit Linux there for nearly a year. Let's say I'm too lazy to upgrade to 64 bit and so as long as 32 bit won't be an obstacle I'll stick to it. But thanks anyway